# MariaDB : UPDATE Table With JOIN have not Match Result

Tags: join, mariadb, sql-update

```
## First I Reset the table 
UPDATE tbl_npwp set 
id_skpd=9999 , saved_from = 9 , update_time = '1999-01-01 00:00:00' ;

## Then  I update 
UPDATE tbl_npwp
join data_spm on tbl_npwp.id_npwp = data_spm.id_npwp
join tbl_unitskpd on tbl_unitskpd.id_unitskpd = data_spm.id_unitskpd
SET 
tbl_npwp.id_skpd = tbl_unitskpd.id_skpd
,tbl_npwp.saved_from = IF(data_spm.id_kontrak > 10 , 1 , 2 )
,tbl_npwp.update_time = data_spm.time_created
WHERE data_spm.id_npwp > 10 ORDER BY data_spm.id_spm desc;
```

After execute  :
tbl_npwp.id_skpd and tbl_npwp.update_time was replaced with <del>only last record of
tbl_unitskpd.id_skpd and data_spm.time_created</del> Record Number 2
of select query result below

i was try this query to proof the result must have different result of update_time and id_skpd

```
SELECT a.id_npwp , b.id_spm , c.id_skpd , b.time_created from tbl_npwp a
join data_spm b on a.id_npwp = b.id_npwp
join tbl_unitskpd c on c.id_unitskpd = b.id_unitskpd
WHERE b.id_npwp > 10 ORDER BY b.id_spm desc;
```

Result :

```
id_npwp     id_spm      id_skpd     time_created    
1026        17407       3       2022-11-21 18:26:24
1495        17406       37      2022-11-17 23:59:10
1191        17405       17      2022-11-15 20:51:35
2027        17404       5       2022-11-15 20:40:22
2026        17403       5       2022-11-15 20:38:32
1878        17402       5       2022-11-15 20:37:15
...
...
```

Notes : All time_created have different value

Comment: Is `ORDER BY data_spm.id_spm desc` really the last record?

Comment: all update record on tbl_npwp.update_time was replaced with : "2022-11-17 23:59:10" and id_skpd=37 when i search data_spm.time_created = "2022-11-17 23:59:10" its located on record number 2 of query result that was i try to proof

Comment: i was found the problem... if i remove order by the result give correct update..but i need ordered data before update cause i want tbl_npwp.saved_from will saved correct data of early data found on data_spm